# Unable to read the LLVM IR corresponding to HelloWorld.bc using llvm-dis

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I have the program `HelloWorld.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
 printf("hello world\n");
 return 0;
}
```

which is compiled to the bitcode `helloWorld.bc` using the command :

```
clang -emit-llvm HelloWorld.c -c -o HelloWorld.bc
```

In order to print the LLVM IR corresponding to `HelloWorld.bc`, I try to disassemble the .bc file.

```
llvm-dis HelloWorld.bc
```

Strangely, the last command outputs nothing to my Terminal. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `llvm-dis HelloWorld.bc` instead of `llvm-dis HelloWorld.c`? And your command `clang -emit-llvm -c -o HelloWorld.bc` seems to be missing the source file parameter `HelloWorld.c`. Anyway, according to the man page, llvm-dis writes to a file `HelloWorld.ll`, not to stdout; please check if that (or any other) file is created.

Answer (score 0):

llvm-dis writes the output to HelloWord.ll not to the Terminal, by the way you can generate human-readable bitcode directly with -S instead of -c while invoking clang.